# Priority in CSS when both id and tag are selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If the priority of the id selector in css is the highest, why are the background colors of the two p's (test1 and test2) are same blue?

[image]

I have tried to change the order of selectors in the style code block and ways to express the id selector. like p #123 {} and #123 p {} .

I want to know the principle and how to use the id selector correctly in this case.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your mistake is naming id.
You must name id without numbers (change it to some word i.e test) and it works.

[image]

Comment: Please post code instead of images. You can use the `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score -2):

Change the id to letters (or let it start with a letter)
The first character of id cannot be a number

Answer (score -3):

ID will be selected before the Tag "#example" will have priority in front of "button tag"

Comment: This is true, however it's clearly not working for the OP - which is why they are asking the question.